# Why most of RAR files I download are corrupted?

Tags: download

I usually download using IDM and all of my downloads are direct links. I had an old computer before and I used to download from certain sites without no problem. Other users don't have any problems too. But recently I use a new computer and I use the same program to download from the same sites.

But 50% of RAR files I download are corrupted. Last night I downloaded a 10GB RAR file using Bittorrent and again it's corrupted and the MD5 checksum is different from the MD5 the original site shows.
Can you tell me what is the main problem ?

Info:
CPU: Intel i7 4770k
RAM: 16GB
HDD: 1TB (from my old computer) + 2TB (new)
All downloads are located in the new HDD that has no bad sector.
Windows 7 Service Pack 1 - WinRAR 5.01 - IDM 6.20 - Tixati 1.96

Comment: How do connect your new computer to the internet? Ethernet? WLan? Other?

Answer (score -1):

Corruption of archives came usually from **bad internet connection**, influence of yours machine is very minimal, almost nonexistent (as long as you have enough free space on hdd for a file).

Basically its can happen from **corrupted or lost packets** - so the problem can be even somewhere "on the way" between server and yours PC. Probability of an error rise with size of archive.

Sometimes is corrupted even original archive file (error in uploading) but if MD5 is different (and if others don't "flag" those), you just must try to download this file again.
Or find other distribution channel for yours data.

But torrent clients should be able to correct those - so my advices are:

- different download client (newest **uTorrent** for example)
- find same **content not packed** (or packed in smaller archives)
- download just **one file at a time** (for faster download)

You can also **test your connection** at http://www.pingtest.net/ or use command line (write `cmd` in start search line and than type (or copy/paste) `ping www.google.com -t`, test is ended by *CTRL+C*
The result time should be usually something between 10ms and 60ms with no packed loss (0%).

Comment: Do you have a cite for this claim? It sounds quite suspicious, since torrenting programs are supposed to detect and repair data errors.

Comment: Which claim do you mean?
I just stated, that if MD5 checksums are different, he should use better torrent client (my suspicion is, that he is NOT using any client at all and just download things by direct link from some site like rapidshare).

Comment: "*Corruption of archives came usually from bad internet connection*"...

Comment: I did the test in Pingtest.net. Report is "Line Quality: C*-MOS 4.12", "Unable to test packet loss". When I try "ping google.com -t" there is 0% loss. I downloaded a 10GB torrent with uTorrent and it was also corrupted. Interesting point is that when I connect my modem to a laptop it downloads just fine! When I contacted my ISP they said the problem is with my PC.